# request-promise throwing Unexpected identifier error when using await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Take this simple GitHub API request example:

```
var request = require('request-promise');

var headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'YOUR_GITHUB_USERID_HERE'
}

var repos = [
    'brandonscript/usergrid-nodejs',
    'facebook/react',
    'moment/moment',
    'nodejs/node',
    'lodash/lodash'
]

function requestPromise(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let json = await request.get(options)
        return `${json.full_name} ${json.stargazers_count}`
    })
}

(async function() {
    for (let repo of repos) {
        let options = {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + repo,
            headers: headers,
            qs: {}, // or put client_id / client_secret here
            json: true
        };
        let info = await requestPromise(options)
        console.log(info)
    }
})()
```

In particular, the line under `requestPromise()` where I use `await`. When running this in Node.js 7.5.0, I get:

```
$ node --harmony awaitTest.js
awaitTest.js:51
        let json = await request.get(options)
                         ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:78:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3
```

If I do it like this, without calling a separate promise, it works:

```
(async function() {
    for (let repo of repos) {
        let options = {}
        let json = await request.get(options)
        let info = json.full_name + ' ' + json.stargazers_count;
        console.log(info) // yay!
    }
})()
```

And I can do this the ES5 way:

```
request.get(options).then(() => resolve(...info...))
```

But when I call out to a separate promise function, it doesn't work. How can I get that to work?

Comment: you need to realise that `await` is only meaningful inside a function declared `async` ...

Comment: I tried declaring it as such too — `async function requestPromise(options) { ...`

Comment: the await is used inside the callback to new Promise, so ... but there's a bigger problem with `requestPromise` ... the promise is never resolved or rejhected

Comment: Hm, good point - trying to sort out how the new syntaxes coexist is confusing ;)

Comment: `async/await` is a step backwards in asynchronous coding ... if you prefer functional over imperative coding :p

Comment: Syntactically yeah, and yet it still feels like a cleaner syntax to write things this way. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using a Promise constructor where you don't need one

simply set requestPromise as async, and then you can do the following

```
async function requestPromise(options) {
    let json = await request.get(options)
    return `${json.full_name} ${json.stargazers_count}`
}
```

Comment: Nicely done — that makes so much more sense. Thanks!